# Getting a list with new line characters

Tags: python, regex

I have a string as below:

```
s = 'hello\n this is\n a forum\n'
```

And I am using a regular expression to get each single/double occurrence of each character. I want to generate a list as `li = [ 'h','e','ll','o','\n','t','h'....]`

I used

```
pattern = re.compile(r'(.)\1?' , re.IGNORECASE)
newList = [m.group() for m in pattern.finditer(s)]
print newList
```

But this gave me `newList= [ 'h','e','ll','o','t','h'....]` , here I could not get the '\n' new line character stored. How should I change my patter to get the '\n' in my list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`re.DOTALL`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.DOTALL) flag like this

```
pattern = re.compile(r'(.)\1?' , re.IGNORECASE | re.DOTALL)
```

Quoting from the docs,

> Make the '.' special character match any character at all, including a
>   newline; without this flag, '.' will match anything except a newline.

I would have preferred [`itertools.groupby`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to do this

```
from itertools import groupby
print ["".join(grp) for char, grp in groupby(s)]
```